# JPA with multiple provider options

Tags: java, jpa

I am working in a project that needs to support customers whith different RDBMs (MSSQL and Oracle specifically). At runtime only a single DB needs to be supported, but the customer wants/can choose which DB to actually use.

The project uses JPA, but has a fairly complex data model, and there are numerous queries that need to be optimized per RDMS, which currently is implemented by (read-only) entities backed by views (instead of real tables).

Currently the project's focus is on one DB (MSSQL) and optimizations have only been relevant there for now; but now the second DB is getting more important.

I am now looking for best practices around using JPA with multiple "providers"(?) like this.

Comment: If you want optimized queries, you have to write them manually. May I suggest jOOQ instead of JPA?

Comment: Sadly jOOQ likely is not an option, price-wise (MSSQL and Oracle seem to need the pricey enterprise tier). thanks for the hint anyway!

Answer (score 0):

JPA implementations like Hibernate perfectly supports the migration cross vendors. Some aspects to consider are described here: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#portability

On the other hand, if you need to have a specific optimization per vendor, i would consider a solution with alternative repositories.

For example CDI offers the use of the @Alternative annotation which lets you package multiple beans that match an injection point without ambiguity errors. In other words, you can apply the @Alternative annotation to two or more beans, then, based on your deployment, specify the bean you want to use in CDI's beans.

More abstract answer is to use a strategy pattern, which lets you to decide during the runtime which repository will be used.

Comment: It's an Spring Data based application, so Spring and no CDI @Alternative, but an analog approach should work there.

Comment: Hope i helped you a little bit :)